# How can I delete those rows in R where two conditions apply?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have two variables "CSO" (1 or 0) and "DateStartRole" (specific date or NA). Now I want to delete those rows within my tibble "refinitiv_boardex" if the variable "CSO" is equal to 1 and at the same time the variable "DateStartRole" has the value "NA".

```
# Remove CSO directors that have NA on their DateStartRole variable
```

```
test <- subset(refinitiv_boardex, refinitiv_boardex$DateStartRole!="NA" & refinitiv_boardex$CSO!=1)
```

Unfortunately, this code causes all lines where the variable "CSO" is 1 to be deleted.

Comment: Try with `!is.na(DateStartRole)`. You are checking for the character string `"NA"` . BTW: In `subset` it it not necessary to use `refinitiv_boardex$`.

Comment: Input:
test <- subset(refinitiv_boardex, !is.na(DateStartRole) & CSO!=1)
count(test, CSO)

Output:
CSO      n
1   0 210887

Unfortunately, it still deletes all CSOs.

Comment: Sorry. My fault. `subset(refinitiv_boardex, !(is.na(DateStartRole) & CSO == 1))` will drop all rows where `DateStartRole` is missing and `CSO` is equal to 1 .

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you provide a sample or example. Let´s say:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) # ymd()

refinitiv_boardex <- tibble(
      CSO = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
      DateStartRole = ymd(NA, "2023-10-07", NA, "2021-12-31", NA))

# A tibble: 5 × 2
    CSO DateStartRole
  <dbl> <date>       
1     1 NA           
2     1 2023-10-07   
3     0 NA           
4     0 2021-12-31   
5     1 NA
```

We want to delete the first and last lines, right? Here´s a possible solution with `dplyr`:

```
refinitiv_boardex <- filter(
  refinitiv_boardex, 
  CSO != 1 | !is.na(DateStartRole))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
    CSO DateStartRole
  <dbl> <date>       
1     1 2023-10-07   
2     0 NA           
3     0 2021-12-31
```

Remember boolean algebra: `not(A and B) = not(A) or not(B)`.